# default password of postgres

Tags: postgresql, docker

I am launching postgres conatainer by placing sql script in docker-initdb. Everything is running fine. But can someone tell **what's the password of my database** created with below script?

```
CREATE DATABASE mydb;

CREATE USER mydbadmin WITH ENCRYPTED PASSWORD 'mypwd';


ALTER DATABASE mydb owner to mydbadmin;

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE mydb TO mydbadmin;
GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE mydb to mydbadmin;
```

I am not providing any explicit password for DB. What would be default password in this case?

How can I provide my explicit password?

Answer (score 0):

A database cannot have a password.

Only roles (users) can authenticate with the PostgreSQL server, so only they can have a password.

Answer (score 0):

- Database has no password, users have passwords. There is no "default password" (i guess that means new users would have pre-set password)
- User `mydbadmin` has the password you have set. Other users will have the password you set when you `CREATE USER`
- Make sure you have necessary settings in `pg_hba.conf`